# Jquery Validity.valid error in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, internet-explorer-8

Validity.valid is null or not an object - having problem with this when using `Internet Explorer 8`

here is part my code:

```
allNextBtn.click(function(){
  var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content_cli"),
      curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
      nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel_cli div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
      curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='email'],input[type='url'],textarea, email,select,select[readonly]"),
      isValid = true;

  $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
  for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
      if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
        isValid = false;
        $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
        $("#"+$(curInputs[i]).attr('id')+"ErrorCLI").show("fast");
        //$(curInputs[0]).closest(".form-group").focus();
      }
      else{
        $("#"+$(curInputs[i]).attr('id')+"ErrorCLI").hide("fast");
      }
  }

  if (isValid)
      nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: because validity is not supported in IE8. Maybe you can find a polyfill

Comment: I'm not familiar with polyfill but will try to search for that, do you know any alternative for validity function that will work in IE 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my own answer to this just in case somebody else have this problem I will post my own solution:

Changing 
if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid)
to
if (curInputs[i].hasAttribute('required') && curInputs[i].value === '' )

this is correct since i'm just checking required fields.